# Intersecting permutations

Tags: algorithms, permutations

Given a subset $P\subset\mathcal{P}_n$ of the permutations of $1,\dots,n$

> **Question:**
> how can a *maximal* subset $p\subseteq\lbrace1,\dots,n\rbrace$ be determined, whose elements appear in the same relative order for every permutation in $P$?

Comment: Since this is a finite problem, it can certainly be done. I suppose the question is, how efficiently can it be done / what are the most efficient methods?

Answer (score 2):

This is also not a full answer, but a bit long for a comment.

If we view each permutation in $P$ as a string of length $n$, then the question can be seen as as instance of the [Longest common subsequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence).
Unfortunately, two bounds $\mathcal{O}(2^n n |P|)$ and $\mathcal{O}(|P| n^{|P|})$ stated on Wikipedia are not that great.

Perhaps it is faster to view it as a ["Longest Subsequence Repeated $k$ Times"](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-subsequence-repeated-k-times/) problem.
Since if we concatenate all of the strings in $P$ into one string $s$. Then the question reduces to finding the longest subsequence in $s$ that is repeated $|P|$ times. This works since every string in $P$ contains each element of $1,\dots,n$ exactly once. However, I'm not sure what the best known complexity is for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This should be seen as a comment:

I was tempted into combinatorial thinking because of the permutations and thus didn't see the solution, while it is actually embarrassingly simple:

take $\lbrace1,\dots,n\rbrace$ as the vertex-set of a possibly asymmetric graph $G$ and add arc $(u,v)$ to $G$ iff $u$ comes before $v$ in a permutation of $P$.

Finally remove all pairs of anti-parallel arcs from $G$; the remaining arcs constitute to the sought maximal intersection; the complexity of a trivial implementation is $O(n^2|P|)$

**Calculation:**

Every permutation can be interpreted as a sequence of directed arcs that define a directed Hamilton path.

Letting $p_1\in P$ be $(1,\dots,n)$ and let $H_1$ be the corresponding directed Hamilton path, we delete from $H_1$ all arcs that appear in opposite direction in another permutation of $P$ and finally the isolated vertices of $H_1$; if we finally "bridge" the gaps in the e.g. the one between $(i,i+1)$ and $(j,j+1), i\lt j$ by adding arcs $(i,j)$ and $(i+1,j+1)$, every path from the source vertex to the sink vertex of that DAG codes a longest path in that DAG.

That reduces the complexity to $O(n|P|)$

If we now delete from $h_1$ all arcs $(i,i+1)$ for which $(i+1,1)$ is an element of some other Hamilton path resembled by some $p\in P$

**python code:**

````
from numpy import random
n = 10 # number of elements to be permuted
k = 3  # number of permutations to generate

arr = [i for i in range(n)]

P = [[]*n]*k
for i in range(len(P)):
    P[i] = [arr[j] for j in range(n)]
    random.shuffle(arr)

path = [[i,i+1] for i in range(n)] +[[n,n]] + [[n,0]]

q = [0]*n
for p in P:
    # calculate the inverse permutation
    for i in range(len(p)):
        q[p[i]]=i # inverse of the permutation 
        
    b = n+1
    a = path[b][1]
    print(p)
    while path[a][1] < n:
        if q[path[a][1]] < q[path[a][0]]:
            print(f'delete a = {a}, path[a][0]={path[a][0]}, path[a][1]={path[a][1]}')
            path[b][1] = path[a][1]
            path[a][1] = n
        else:
            b = a
        
        a = path[b][1]

        
intersection =[(path[i][0],path[i][1]) for i in range(n) if path[i][0]<n and path[i][1]<n]
print(f'\nintersection={intersection}')
            

```
````

Comment: What we are looking for is a maximal clique in the remaining graph. In general this is a hard problem. But possibly for such graphs it is not.

Comment: @FedorPetrov every connected component of the underlying symmetric graph must be a clique; therefore reporting one of the largest connected components solves the problem.
The ordered sequence of the elements can be recoverd by calculating a directed Hamilton path in the DAG of the oriented arcs of such a clique.

Comment: Why is every connected component a clique? Consider the permutations 123 and 213, then the graph contains edges 13,23 but not 12.

Comment: @FedorPetrov you are right, things are more complicated than they seemed to me

Comment: @FedorPetrov  ...but isn't it the case that the vertices of every directed path in remaining DAG must belong to a clique in the underlying symmetric graph and that the vertices of a longest directed path resemble a solution? If that is the case, the problem could be reduced to finding the longest directed path in a DAG, which can be solved in time linear in the number of arcs.

Comment: Ah, yes. Moreover, this is a "longest chain in a poset" problem.

Comment: I agree with @FedorPetrov's interpretation – it's clearest if you see this in terms of partial order relations rather than directed graphs. Each permutation defines a linear order with $O(n^2)$ pairs. Just keep track of the intersection of these linear orders as permutations arrive. Finally, use a "longest chain" algorithm on the final partial order – it helps that you already have a linear extension to scan through! The whole thing will take $O(n^2|P|)$, as you originally stated. It remains an interesting question whether that can be reduced, but maybe that's good enough for you already!